# Is there a way to open synaptic package manager with specific Custom Filter selected?

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I have created a custom filter for specific set of tools. I want to start SPM (synaptic package manager) with the above mentioned filter so that synaptic open with list of tools I wants to show.

I see that editing /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf file makes changes in SPM interface. On setting  ViewMode "3"; SPM starts with Custom  filter option selected. Like the same I could not find any parameter for selecting specific filter from all shown.

There is one more file /root/.synaptic/filters with all filters definition. Is there any parameter to be set in this file so as to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man synaptic`:

```
OPTIONS
       Synaptic accepts all of the standard Gtk+ toolkit command line options as well as the following:

       -f, --filter-file=filename
              specify an alternative filter settings file

       -i, --initial-filter=int
              apply the filter with number int at startup

       -o, --option=option
              set an internal option (experts only)
```

---

To open synaptic with a specific Custom Filter selected from terminal, you would just do

```
sudo synaptic -i=? (replace the ? with your filter)
```

For example to open synaptic with the Broken filter as in the image below, you would just do

```
sudo synaptic -i=Broken
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked.... but still is there any other way to achieve same requirement by opening synaptic through GUI?

Comment: For gui just alter the Exec= line of /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop or create another .desktop for synaptic with a different name of the .desktop & altered Name= & Exec= lines. Eg. `Exec=synaptic-pkexec -i=?` If the filter has a space then use ', Ex. - `Exec=synaptic-pkexec -i='Upgradable (upstream)'`

Comment: it worked! In my case for a separate filter file it worked like Exec=synaptic-pkexec -f=/pathto/myfilter -i filter_name